# How to show alert when GIT pushed in Idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How to show alert when GIT pushed in Idea? I just want to be sure my project were pushed.

Comment: Sorry, but I see nothing when project pushed. Just Push loader hiding.

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow don't see any confirmation, you can do:

- a `git fetch` ([IntelliJ IDEA Fetch operation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/fetching-changes-from-a-remote-git-repository.html))
- and check the [`git log` in IntelliJ IDEA](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/git-log-gets-more-power/): see if your `HEAD` and `origin/yourBranch` match.